# How did Delphi influence the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, history, delphi

As opposed to influence on the C# language, did Delphi influence the .NET Framework too? At first glance .NET is Microsoft's version of Java, but .NET has properties similar to Delphi. Are there other influences?

Comment: You've asked 8 Pascal history question in the last 30 minutes. Are you doing a research project on it or something?

Comment: @Morons I Tried to ask them all in one question (my preferred method), but I was told that was inappropriate by the moderators and that I need to ask specific questions. It is a lot more work for me, and clutters up the question stream, but I guess that is the way the moderators want it. I would suggest you add a ignore flag instead of leaving rude and non-constructive comments.

Comment: @unholysample: I am putting together a history. I tried asking all these questions in one question, but the moderators shot me down and said to ask individual questions. Now we all suffer.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth: My point was more that asking random people on the internet is not a good way to do research. You might find someone that has some good primary sources, but in general, you are going to get people going off memory or pointing to things they found with google.

Comment: Is there an IT history Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Unholy I've found Stack Exchange a good way to tap into experts. We will see how it goes.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9912/history-of-computers-and-computing

Comment: @Morons Following it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Anders Hejlsberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) developed Delphi, then was poached by MS to work on their Java implementation. When that fell by the wayside, he moved to a new language code-named 'cool', which was C#.